# Accessing Functions and Variables from Another Class

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a **Main** class and a **GameScreen** class. In the **GameScreen** class, I have a button that returns the user to the main menu. However, my **gotoMainMenu** function is in the **Main** class. I tried making the **gotoMainMenu** function static, but inside that function I call non-static functions.

Currently I have this code which passes the **gotoMainMenu** function into my **gameScreen** object:

```
gameScreen = new GameScreen(gotoMainMenu);
```

In the **GameScreen** constructor I assign this to an instance variable, and then I add an event listener using that instance variable as the second parameter, like this:

```
backArrowButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoMainMenuMainFunction);
```

Is this a good way to do this? If not, can you provide another solution that is not considered bad coding?

I have another problem that is very similar. I have a **Hero** class which needs access to many of the variables in my **GameScreen** class. I know static variables are a fix, but I was taught that this is bad coding, and that static variables should only be used for constants.

Currently, I pass in instance variables as parameters like this:

```
hero = new Hero(levelData, map, gameCont);
```

Then in the **Hero** class I assign these parameters to instance variables, very similar to how I pass in functions. These variables refer to the same object. I need to pass in primitive data types into the onEnterFrame function like this:

```
hero.onEnterFrame(up, left, right, mouse);
```

The problem with this is that I do not like storing instance variables, that refer to the same object, in 2 separate classes. I feel like there is a much better way to do this. Please provide a solution to these 2 problems, and make sure that it is not considered bad coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your solution of your first problem is indeed considered a bad coding practice.

Now let's get on with good ways to fix your problems. As I see you are creating a `GameScreen` instance in your `Main` class. That means you have a reference to that object, therefore you can add an event listener for a custom event that tells your `Main` class to return to main menu. Your code would be something like this:

```
// you just create your instance, without the Function parameter
gameScreen = new GameScreen();

// then you add an event listener for your custom event
gameScreen.addEventListener(MyGameEvent.GOTO_MAIN_MENU, gotoMainMenu);
```

Now note that this will pass an instance of your custom event as a parameter to the `gotoMainMenu` method, so the definition of your `gotoMainMenu` method should be something like this:

```
private function gotoMainMenu(e:MyGameEvent):void {...}
// or if you'd like to call this method on a click, use the parent of all events Event class:
private function gotoMainMenu(e:Event):void {...}
```

Note that we changed the `MyGameEvent` class with more general `Event` class.

Now you have to create `MyGameEvent` to add custom types and even custom data if needed.
For this you have to extend `Event` class like this:

```
package
{
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class MyGameEvent extends Event
    {
        public static const GOTO_MAIN_MENU:String = "MyGameEvent.GOTO_MAIN_MENU";

        public function MyGameEvent(type:String, bubbles:Boolean = false, cancelable:Boolean = false)
        {
            super(type, bubbles, cancelable);
        }
    }
}
```

When you need to return to main menu from the `GameScreen` just call the `dispatchEvent` method inherited from the `EventDispatcher` class (`Sprites` and `MovieClips` also have this method, since they inherit `EventDispatcher`):

```
dispatchEvent(new MyGameEvent(MyGameEvent.GOTO_MAIN_MENU));
```

If compiler gives you an error on this call, make sure your `GameScreen` class extends one of these: `EventDispatcher`, `Sprite` or `MovieClip`.

Passing references to your `Hero` class isn't that bad, it can become cumbersome in big projects as it couples your code, but you can use some design patterns as a solution, as Pier suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Passing references is not bad coding per se. Also each reference only occupies a few bytes of memory.

The problem with using references that way is that your code becomes coupled, and in the long run you don't want that. Of course if you have a project with 3 classes it won't really matter, but in larger projects it becomes essential to keep your mental sanity and be able to reuse your code.

To solve those coupling problem some guys invented a number of different [design patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns) a long time ago. To solve your communication problems you could for example use the [Observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) or the [Singleton pattern](http://gskinner.com/blog/archives/2006/07/as3_singletons.html).

Another option instead of passing references would be using events. If you go this way I strongly recommend using [Robert Penner's Signals](https://github.com/robertpenner/as3-signals).